# Undefined method 'json' in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, api

I'm trying to get data from external API and show the data in json form, unexpectedly i got this "Undefined method json" error, how do i solve this?

Below is my controller code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class alkitabcontroller extends Controller
{
    public function getDataAlkitab(Request $request){
        $kitab = $request->input('kitab');
        $pasal = $request->input('pasal');

        $client = new Client;
        $request = $client->get("https://api-alkitab.herokuapp.com/v2/passage/$kitab/$pasal?ver=tb");
        $response = $request->json();
        dd($response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [discussed at length](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1106#issuecomment-108017863) in the Guzzle Github the `json` method was polarising and against the switch to `PSR-7` only interfaces, so it was removed.

Therefore, you either create your own implementation or just :

```
$client = new Client;
$response = $client->get("https://api-alkitab.herokuapp.com/v2/passage/$kitab/$pasal?ver=tb");
$json_string = $response->getBody()->getContents();
$json = json_decode($json_string);
dd($json);
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to convert to json is by using [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
json_encode($request->all());
```

Comment: That is the RAW way of doing it... If you are using a framework, it would mostly be already encoded when you share an array or similar...